# Laravel How to update a calendar event by using Cronofy API

Tags: php, laravel, cronofy

In my `laravel`-application I want to include my `google-calendar` by using the [Cronofy API](https://docs.cronofy.com/developers/api/) and the package from [cronofy-php](https://github.com/cronofy/cronofy-php).

Now when I try to update an event, the event gets duplicated and I don't really know why:

Here is my code:

```
public function updateEvent(){

   $cronofy = new Cronofy\Cronofy([
      "client_id" => config('cronofy.client_id'),
      "client_secret" => config('cronofy.client_secret'),
      "access_token" => $access_token->value,
      "refresh_token" => $refresh_token->value
   ]);


   $new_start_date = date("Y-m-d\TH:m:s\Z", strtotime(request()->event['changes']['start']['_date']));
   $new_end_date = date("Y-m-d\TH:m:s\Z", strtotime(request()->event['changes']['end']['_date']));

    $params = [
       'calendar_id' => (string)request()->event['schedule']['calendarId'],
       'event_id' => (string)request()->event['schedule']['id'],
       'summary' => request()->event['schedule']['title'],
       'description' => request()->event['schedule']['body'],
       'start' =>  (object)['time' => $new_start_date, 'tzid' => 'Etc/UTC'],
       'end' => (object)['time' => $new_end_date, 'tzid' => 'Etc/UTC'],
   ];

   $updated_event = $cronofy->upsertEvent($params);

   return response(['success' => true, 'event' => $params]);

}
```

As mentioned above, this creates a duplicate of the event, which I intentionally want to update/edit.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

So the way I am seeing it you are creating a new Cronofy Object and afterwards upserting it which will lead to it being inserted. To only edit the existing calendar event you should use edit the already existing Object
So instead of:

```
public function updateEvent(){

$cronofy = new Cronofy\Cronofy([
      "client_id" => config('cronofy.client_id'),
      "client_secret" => config('cronofy.client_secret'),
      "access_token" => $access_token->value,
      "refresh_token" => $refresh_token->value
   ]);
...
```

It should be something like

```
public function updateEvent($id){

$cronofy = Cronofy\Cronofy::find($id);

$new_start_date = date("Y-m-d\TH:m:s\Z", strtotime(request()->event['changes']['start']['_date']));
$new_end_date = date("Y-m-d\TH:m:s\Z", strtotime(request()->event['changes']['end']['_date']));

$params = [
   'calendar_id' => (string)request()->event['schedule']['calendarId'],
   'event_id' => (string)request()->event['schedule']['id'],
   'summary' => request()->event['schedule']['title'],
   'description' => request()->event['schedule']['body'],
   'start' =>  (object)['time' => $new_start_date, 'tzid' => 'Etc/UTC'],
   'end' => (object)['time' => $new_end_date, 'tzid' => 'Etc/UTC'],
];

$updated_event = $cronofy->upsertEvent($params);
...
```

I hope I could help